# PLEASE HELP, Problems with creating new users in database

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, database-connection, registration

This is my first (of many, hopefully) questions. I am creating a simple login system for a site I'm working on for uni and I have a page that allows the client to add a new user to the database;

```js
<?php
//INSERT//

$host="localhost"; 
$username="root"; 
$password="";  
$db_name="login";  
$tbl_name="members"; 

//variables//

$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$query = "INSERT INTO members VALUES ('','myusername','mypassword'')";

        mysql_query($query);

echo ''.$_POST['myusername'].' has been added as a new user'.'<br/>' ;

mysql_close();
?>
```

This echo's that "myusername" has been added as a new user, though it doesn't insert anything into the 'members' table. Why is this? It appears to be working ok. I've had to insert an temporary user with an insert script for the time being which works but I really need the user to have the ability to do this themselves. Here is the script I used that works:

```js
<?php
$user="root";
$password="";
$database="login";
mysql_connect('localhost',$user,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query="INSERT INTO `members` VALUES (1, 'kerr', '1234')";


mysql_query($query);
mysql_close();
?>
```

I hope this makes sense. Thank in advance! Kerr

Comment: check first what query is doing?

Comment: share your HTML part as well please... and your database structure if you can.

Comment: I gues the mysql connect in the first piece of code is wrong? quoted the variables between the ().

Comment: place insert into query with column name

Comment: If the query is failing, use `mysql_error` to see what the problem is. Even better - don't use `mysql_` functions, and switch to PDO or `mysqli_` - you can use prepared statements and bound parameters to do this, and your code will be much more secure.

Comment: Hi! The database is called 'login' the table is called 'members' and the columns are called 'id' , 'username' and 'password'. Which part of the html would help? The php for //INSERT// is in a container div inside a larger html document.  Sorry I I sound like a complete beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set 'members' table 'id' column to auto_increment.

try:

```
$insert = mysql_query($query);

if($insert){
echo ''.$_POST['myusername'].' has been added as a new user'.'<br/>' ; 
}
else{
echo mysql_error($insert);
}
```

Do you have form tag in the HTML file?

Comment: I tried that it gave me (Warning: mysql_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\JLBDigitalArchive\add_user.php on line 86) Line 86 in the code is; echo mysql_error($insert);

Comment: $query = "INSERT INTO members VALUES (' ','myusername','mypassword' ')"; <----you have two ' before the )...remove one.

Can you var_dump($insert); ?

Comment: I added a $ before myusername and mypassword an they are now entering into the table correctly! However it inserts two identical rows??

Comment: Got it working through tinkering, I had two $query's which inputted each user twice and the ID would not allow more than one user with the same name. Or something like that. Anyway thanks for all the help!